# Find $(\delta-\alpha)(\gamma-\alpha)(\delta-\beta)(\gamma-\beta)$ as a polynomial of p,q,r,s

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The equation $x^2+px+q=0$ has roots $\alpha , \beta$; the equation $y^2+ry+s=0$has roots $\delta, \gamma$. Find $$(\delta-\alpha)(\gamma-\alpha)(\delta-\beta)(\gamma-\beta)$$ as a polynomial of p,q,r,s.( This polynomial is called the resultant of two quadratic polynomials, it is equal to zero if these two polynomials have a common root.)

The question comes from Gelfand and Shen 'Algebra' . It comes after a section on  Vieta's Theorem $$\alpha + \beta = -p$$
$$\alpha.\beta = q$$
I have tried multiplying out the brackets but I can't see how to relate the terms to p,q,r and s.  I think the problem is designed to be solved with basic algebra.

Comment: You could use the ABC formula for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ and then substitute those values in the required expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
x^2+px+q=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)
$$
implies
$$
(\delta-\alpha)(\delta-\beta)=\delta^2+p\delta+q
$$
and
$$
(\gamma-\alpha)(\gamma-\beta)=\gamma^2+p\gamma+q.
$$
It reduces to compute 
$$
(\delta^2+p\delta+q)(\gamma^2+p\gamma+q).
$$
Expanding it, then applying the other Vieta's Theorem, the result is
$$
q^2+s^2-pqr-srp+qr^2+sp^2-2sq.
$$

Comment: Leaving the expansion gave me just enough to do to help me understand what was going on . Thank you .

Comment: @mikoyan You are welcome!